# Ubuntu dock is not available after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock

I have recently upgraded to 18.04, but had some issues during upgrade which resulted in absence of dock. Dock tab is also empty in settings. How can I install dock and enable it?

Update:

this is how my dock settings look
[image: settings image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check whether Ubuntu dock is installed by running the following command in Terminal

```
apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock | grep Installed
```

If the output is `Installed: (none)` then it is not installed and you can install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

Otherwise there is a possibility that you're not in the default Ubuntu session. When you boot your system and get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find an *Ubuntu* (and *Ubuntu on Wayland*) option. Select it and then log in.

---

As @Videonauth pointed out, you may also use the "Dash to Dock" extension (Ubuntu dock is a fork of Dash to Dock) as a workaround. You can install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock
```

or from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/). You can then manage your installed extensions using `gnome-tweaks`.

Comment: Or if he wants it he could install `gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock` as an alternative which has more options to customize it. Never the less in both ways he might need to install `gnome-tweak-tool` to change it.